# How to unsubscribe from Firestore realtime listener which is wrapped in an rxjs observable?

Tags: firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have written a function that returns an observable that wraps the firestore `onSnapshot` method.

```
function getObservable() {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
      firebase.firestore().collection('users').onSnapshot(
        snapshot => observer.next(snapshot.docs),
      );
    });
  })
}
```

I am able to use this function and get updated docs as follows

```
const observable = getObservable()
const subscription = observable.subscribe(users => console.log('users'));
```

If I now call the `subscription.unsubscribe()` method, I will unsubscribe from the subscription. However, I will not subscribe from the `onSnapshot` listener.

Is there any way such that when I unsubscribe from the observable, I will automatically unsubscribe from the `onSnapshot` method.

Comment: you fire the listener empty. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From RxJS documentation (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-create):

> **onSubscription** can optionally **return either a function or an object
>   with unsubscribe method**. In both cases **function or method will be
>   called when subscription to Observable is being cancelled** and should
>   be used to clean up all resources. So, for example, if you are using
>   setTimeout in your custom Observable, when someone unsubscribes, you
>   can clear planned timeout, so that it does not fire needlessly and
>   browser (or other environment) does not waste computing power on
>   timing event that no one will listen to anyways.

So, if I have understood this right, you may want to try something similar to this

```
function getObservable() {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
      const unsubscribe = firebase.firestore().collection('users').onSnapshot(
        snapshot => observer.next(snapshot.docs),
      );
      return unsubscribe;
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: Note: `Observable.create` is deprecated, use `new Observable()` instead https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3982.